# how to return sample json data in response from angular service class

Tags: angular

How to return sample json data in response instead of calling actual API.
I want to test my UI code without actually calling backend API .I have response data captured from UAT
I have added this in my service and put json file in same folder.

```
     getdata(): Observable<any>{
return this.http.get<any>('keyinfoResponse.json')
.pipe(map((data)=>data),catchError((error)=>throwError(error)));
```

}

and in component

```
this.dataService.getdata().subscribe((response) => {
     
      this.keyInfoResponse = response;
    }, (error) => {
      this.hasErrorOccurred = true;      
      if (error.message) {
        this.errorMessage = error.message;
      }       
    });
  }
```

the response is undefined.

Comment: whats the issue ?

Comment: put the json in 'assets' folder, and change your url in the service to 'assets/keyinfoResponse.json'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a local .json file using the HttpClient, the location of the file must be included in the `assets` property of `angular.json` file. By default (in most cases), the `src/assets` folder will already be included.

**angular.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "site": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

So either need to place the .json files in the `src/assets` folder or if not, add their source folder path to the `assets` property.

Folder structure

```
src
├── app
├── assets
│   ├── keyinfoResponse.json
├── angular.json
├── index.html
...
```

Then you could access them using the HttpClient like the following

```js
getdata(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>('assets/keyinfoResponse.json').pipe(
    map((data) => data),
    catchError((error) => throwError(error))
  );
}
```